# How to install exp globally through npm

Tags: npm, expo

After running `npm install -g exp` in my cmd running in administrator mode successfully, I am unable to get `exp --version` or any other command with `exp` receiving

```
'exp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

please tell me how I can install Exp globally on my windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently adding `C:\Users\~\AppData\Roaming\npm` ~ being your username in the pc, to environment variables will solve the problem.

Comment: So, It means your `npm` was not set to the environment and if so then how can you able to manage to download `exp` in the first attempt? I just wonder. It should give you an error about `npm` command not found.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `exp` doesn't installed correctly.

Please check by the following command:

```
1. npm list -g
2. npm view exp version
3. npm list -g --depth=0
```

3rd will give you list of packages something like this:

```
├── @angular/cli@1.7.4
├── @ngtools/json-schema@1.2.0
├── @ngtools/logger@1.1.2
├── @ngtools/webpack@1.10.2
├── async@2.6.1
├── asynch@0.5.2
├── hsbot@1.0.3
├── istanbul@0.4.5
├── n@2.1.12
├── node-gyp@3.6.2
├── npm@6.1.0
├── r-script@0.0.3
├── readline@1.3.0
├── typescript@2.8.1
```

If still, you found an error. Try to re-install it using root user.

You can follow this step:

1. `npm uninstall -g exp` (Remove corrupted package if so)
2. `npm cache clean --force` (This is not necessary. But, sometime npm cache gets confused)
3. `npm i -g exp` (And reinstall again `exp` package)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can install `expo-cli`.

Use this code:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```